# google calendar sync infinite loop

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am developing a Google calendar sync application on Android. I have used `SyncAdapter` for it. I am done with the login part, receiving and parsing response from Google calendar api.

When I click on Sync Calendar option under Data & Synchronization, it goes under infinite sync loop which keeps on running until I uncheck the checkbox.

So my question is, repeated sync is normal behaviour or not? If not then please tell me where I am going wrong..

Answer (score 0):

I think this largely depends the process you are using to sync the calendar resources.

I have found in the past that using events > list and setting singleEvents to TRUE (i.e. returns single instances of recurring events), any recurring events that have no end date will essentially never finish processing the results of the query. This is because there actually is no end to the results...